# Why have I seen a blank screen after installing Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, installation, server-setup, magento2.4

I have installed new Magento 2.4 following the guide on Magento website using command line no composer, but all I'm getting is blank pages so far,
it's installed on AWS using Nginx, any ideas on how to troubleshoot the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your server logs, probably there is some server incompatibility, you can check possible incompatibilities running this command below:

```
curl -O https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && 
chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && 
alias n98="./n98-magerun2.phar" &&
n98 sys:check
```

Run this command to set your store in **developer** mode, so you can see more logs in the frontend.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Answer (score 0):

can you paste the problem logs or screen shots ?

Generally Magento installation is -

- get magento repo keys
- clone repo
- create db
- composer install ( add keys to auth.json in root folder or on composer prompt)
- use cli setup or web setup wizard to complete setup
- bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
- bin/magento set:up